# How do I return a html code as output of filter in Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have written a custom filter which matches a pattern and if the match is true converts it into html, how do I bind the html output inside {{test | toimgsrc}} I don't want to use ng-bind-html or $sce is there any other way?
here is my code

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['toimage'])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = '*!dsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd!*';
  });
angular.module('toimage', []).filter('toimgsrc', function() {
  return function(text) {
    regex = /^\*!(\w*)!\*$/;
    if (regex.test(text))
      return text.replace(/^\*!(\w*)!\*$/, '<h2 class="bolder">"$1" </h2>')
    else
      return text;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
  {{test | toimgsrc}}
  <div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the angular documentation say:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

By default, Angular only loads templates from the same domain and protocol as the application document. This is done by calling $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl on the template URL. To load templates from other domains and/or protocols, you may either whitelist them or wrap it into a trusted value.

that means you are converting the value to html, that also need to be secure, that is the reason the only way to solve that is with $sce like this:

```
$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(yourGeneratedHtml);


<div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"> </div>
```

The main reason for that is for the security policy that angular handle.

Comment: Thank you! seems like I have to stick to either of them in that case.